# SQL Server : OPENROWSET - Read Empty Text File Error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I've encountered an error when using `openrowset` to read an empty text file. I've been trying to use HDR/HEADER properties, but still get this error, any alternatives?

SQL Server version: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

```
select *
from openrowset(  'MSDASQL','Driver={Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)}; Extended Properties="HDR=NO"',
   'select * from E:\[empty_text_file.txt]')
```

Error:

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "(null)" returned message "[Microsoft][ODBC Text Driver] Query must have at least one destination field"

Comment: If it's empty, what are you expecting?

Comment: Actually I was doing return row count, I just expect 0 or null

Comment: But a file that contains nothing doesn't even have 0 rows; rows arent applicable.

Comment: I see, then i would need to apply verification before load in, thanks